# Is 'È oggi che c'è...' grammatically correct?

Tags: word-order, conjunctions

Let's have a look at this sentence.

> Oggi c'è la festa di Carlo.

If you want to emphasise the fact that the party is today, you can say 'La festa di Carlo è oggi' or 'È oggi la festa di Carlo', can't you? I've heard people say

> È oggi che c'è la festa di Carlo.

too. Is this grammatically correct? It sounds to me like a contraction of a longer form, such as 'È oggi *il giorno in cui* c'è la festa di Carlo'.

Comment: Interesting. This is not an answer, but I'd say that it is both correct and quite frequently used. As to it being a contraction, I doubt it, since we can also say something like “fu in questo periodo che [accadde una certa cosa]”, where no paraphrase with “in cui” is possible (unless we modify the sentence: “fu questo il periodo in cui [accadde una certa cosa]”).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence you proposed is an example of a construction called ["frase scissa"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frase-scissa_(La-grammatica-italiana)/). Vittorio Coletti, in his book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, explains:

> E tutte le volte che si spezza una frase semplice ricavandone, a scopo di sottolineatura, una seconda («viene Andrea» > «è Andrea che viene»; «quando vieni?» > «quand'è che vieni?»), cioè nelle cosiddette frasi scisse (cfr. cap. IX), scomposte in due, è ancora *che*, tra relativo e congiunzionale, a farla da padrone.

That is, with this mechanism, one breaks a simple sentence with the purpose of giving emphasis to some part of it, obtaining a complex sentence divided in two clauses, one of them introduced always by "che" (which can be a relative pronoun or a conjunction).

This mechanism is explained with more detail in chapter IX of this book:

> Prendiamo la frase già incontrata «canta Mario», risposta con posticipazione del soggetto all'ipotetica domanda «chi canta?». Se la riscriviamo così: «è Mario che canta», diamo al soggetto un duplice rilievo: segue il primo verbo (*è*) ma precede il secondo (*canta*) tramite un pronome relativo (*che*). Si tratta della cosiddetta «frase scissa», costrutto anch'esso secolare dell'italiano, capace di dare evidenza speciale tanto al soggetto quanto ai complimenti; possiamo infatti anche dire, invece di «Mario mangia la mela», «è la mela che Mario mangia»; invece di «Mario ha dato il libro a Carlo», «è a Carlo che Mario ha dato il libro», ottenendo un'espressività in certi casi utile; sono strutture sintattiche tipiche e quasi riservate all'orale, che fanno concorrenza alle dislocazioni per efficacia espressiva. [...] Oggi si trova sempre più frequentemente.

So, using this mechanism, you can give emphasis to the subject or to any of the complements of the sentence. The author explains that this kind of sentences are not to be considered grammatically incorrect (he says explicitly at some point in this chapter "non è sbagliato"), but they are more typically used in oral communication. However, it is nowadays sometimes found in written texts, in contexts that are not very formal:

> La frase scissa, costrutto originariamente soprattutto dell'orale, si va propogando allo scritto, almeno in certe sue tipologie. Non solo nello scritto che riproduce il parlato, come logico (Enrico Testa lo ha ben illustrato nella novella antica e nel romanzo italiano di Otto e Novecento), ma anche in quello argomentativo, purché sufficientemente informale, disinvolto, elastico. In un articolo di Eugenio Scalfari sulla «Repubblica» del 16 novembre 2014 leggiamo: «Il Partito della nazione è democratico, al suo interno si discute liberamente... Discute anche con il leader, ma poi è lui che decide», e nella frase scissa conclusiva non ci troviamo nulla di male, come, credo, non c'è niente di male nella dislocazione con ripresa pronominale che ho usato io («nella frase scissa... ci...») per dirlo.

Comment: I think I couldn't expect a clearer answer! Very interesting indeed.